# Eclipse Plugin Settings - Activation and Singleton Settings

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde, manifest.mf

In the Eclipse manifest editor, there exist check boxes for enabling/disabling plug-in activation and singleton behavior, as shown below:

```
[ ] Activate this plug-in when one of its classes is loaded
[ ] This plug-in is a singleton
```

#### Questions:

1. When would the activation check box **NOT** be checked?
2. If wrapping a third-party library, should this plug-in *"usually"* be configured as a singleton?

I'm searching for information or some examples that would demonstrate when activation of the plugin would not be desired (*i.e.*, intentional non-activation).  The singleton behavior is clearer (in my opinion) to see when it would be appropriate (*e.g.*, a logger).

Much thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. When you both don't a) need to do anything special when the plug-in starts and stops; b) don't have any extensions in `plugin.xml` which are only picked up on activation. However, those are circumstances where you **can** not activate. Since it's easy enough to forget about turning automatic activation on when they change, I'd still check the option even in this case. I don't know of any situation where you'd actively want to turn automatic activation off.
2. No, usually not. Only when two instances of this plug-in would interfere with each other. As you suggest, a logger (both would try to write to same files), a printing library, a graphics toolkit, etc.

Comment: Thank you Alexey, you helped me to understand more about plug-in activation.