# Lazy activation of Eclipse plugins

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp

I would like to know what is "Activate this plug-in when one of its classes is loaded" check-box in Eclipse manifest editor useful for.

I thought Eclipse always use "lazy initialization" approach. Does have this option a relation to the BundleActivator class of the plugin? is initialization something different to activation?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997614/eclipse-plugin-settings-activation-and-singleton-settings) is a similar question, but I don't understand it entirely.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ticking the box causes the following header to be set in the manifest:

```
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

I'll start with how "pure" OSGi deals with this. IF the bundle is started with the START_ACTIVATION_POLICY flag then the bundle enters the `STARTING` state but the activator's start() method is not invoked and a ClassLoader is not allocated for the bundle. The bundle stays in STARTING until, for whatever reason, a class needs to be loaded from the bundle. At that point a ClassLoader is allocated and the activator (if any) is instantiated and its start() method is invoked before the requested class is loaded.

However Eclipse layers additional semantics on the top. As background, Eclipse always tries to avoid starting bundles in order to keep its start-up time minimal. A very small core set of bundles is started by default (the list is in configuration/config.ini) and one of these is called the p2 "simpleconfigurator". The simpleconfigurator looks for bundles that have the `Bundle-ActivationPolicy:lazy` header and it starts them with the START_ACTIVATION_POLICY flag... therefore these bundles will be "lazily" started as described above.

The important point is that **all** other bundles that do not contain the header **will not be started at all** under Eclipse. They will stay in RESOLVED state, their activators will not be invoked, and if they contain any Declarative Services component they will not be loaded. This is because Declarative Services only ever looks at bundles that are in ACTIVE or STARTING state.

**Therefore the main reason to use the header is if we want to write a bundle containing Declarative Services components that need to work under Eclipse.**

In other environments there is *no need to use the header*. Most normal OSGi apps simply start all bundles, rather than trying to selectively start a subset of bundles. Note that this doesn't mean OSGi apps don't worry about lazy loading! Declarative Services already supports lazy loading without messing around with bundle class loading triggers. In my opinion Eclipse gets this wrong and has added unnecessary complexity to the bundle lifecycle. Nevertheless if you are running in Eclipse then you have no choice but to understand and work with its limitation.

Comment: Nice answer. Still I have few questions. 1) When I set a plugin in product configuration to autoStart:true, then it will be started irrespective of the Bundle-ActivationPolicy header? 2) What does starting mean anyway? You say "they will not be started at all". How can a plugin work when it's not started?

Comment: 1) Yes. 2) Started means that the bundle's activator is invoked and the DS components are instantiated/managed. A non-started bundle (i.e. RESOLVED) can still provide dependencies, e.g. export packages that can be loaded by other bundles. This is useful for things like passive libraries.

Comment: By the way, the DS you are talking about. They are all those extension points like menu contribution, workbench parts contribution etc? Because when I create a plugin that contribute a view to a perspective and don't set it Bundle-ActivationPolicy:lazy, the view is still visible!?

Comment: No, DS is for OSGi Services, you're talking about Eclipse extensions, which are declared in plugin.xml. They do NOT require the bundle to be active, only RESOLVED (another wrong choice by Eclipse, by the way...).

Comment: I always thought the Eclipse extensions are build upon OSGi services.

Comment: Nope. Eclipse extensions were designed before Eclipse adopted OSGi (in Eclipse 3.0, back in around 2004), and since then have existed in parallel with them. Eclipse 4.x makes more use of services than previously, but the Extension Registry is still heavily used.